# Dynamic Tabs - Removing tabs - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dynamic, tabs

I'm attempting to remove tab items from a list of dynamically created tabs (created by clicking on elements in a table elsewhere). In the Plunker example, these are just created using a loop.

**EDIT**: There isn't actually anything *wrong* with this. I just think that I'm not doing it the "angular way".

I've managed to get it to delete tabs, however the way I have done it seems wrong and I haven't the faintest idea on how to get it to be "right". The issue occurs when attempting to delete a tab. When clicking on the X, the tab will empty and be removed from the array. However, the tab header will not be.

You can see this in action if you change the following line from the plunker

```
<a href="#" ng-click="tab.$parent.tabManager.removeTab($index);tabs.splice($index, 1);" ><span style="margin-left:0.5rem">X</span></a>',
```

to

```
<a href="#" ng-click="tab.$parent.tabManager.removeTab($index);" ><span style="margin-left:0.5rem">X</span></a>',
```

The usage of the `tabs.splice($index, 1);` function inside the ng-click seems incorrect, is there some other way I could do this? Am I just doing it all wrong?

Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/87PB7wEYss8hTs8zduf5)

Comment: I'm not clear on your problem. In the plnkr provided, the item spliced from the list is the correct item. Could you elaborate?

Comment: There's nothing actually wrong with how it works. It just doesn't seem the angular way and part of me thinks there must be a better way to do it, but it eludes me :|

Comment: Is the dynamicTabs directive going to be reused, or is it tightly coupled to the dynamicTabController?

Comment: Hmm I think it's a code review you're looking for. I took a quick look, there are areas that could use re-writing but it doesn't seem dramatically out of line with Angular style/conventions.

Comment: I would like it to be reusable in other places in my application, so I'm trying to keep it as isolated as possible.